# Can't print A3 on ricoh mp 3555

Tags: printing, printer

When I try to print on A3 all documents are printed on A4.
Tray 4 has A3 paper in landscape, printer is set to automatically detect paper size.

Any idea why it acts like this?

Comment: It's the application and driver that determine the paper that will be used, **not** the printer. For example, Word will ignore all paper settings, **unless** they are made from Page Setup. So, what is the application you're printing from?

Comment: Excel 2013, but i've setup A3 page...

Comment: I've also forced to print on A3 and it printed a A4 page on A3 paper...

Comment: In Excel, did you select A3 in Page Setup (Page Layout tab)? 

I'm not sure what you mean by "forced to print on A3".